# Validate a domain in a query_string for rewritecond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

The webserver i'm using is Apache 2.2. I'm trying to validate a domain that is in a query string sent by an external party.

An example of a valid request:
https://something.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc?returnurl=https://test.example.com/home

examples of invalid requests:

1. scheme://something.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc?returnurl=https://something.evil.com/home
2. scheme://something.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc?returnurl=http://www.google.com
3. scheme://something.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccct?returnurl=https://something.evil.com/blah?url=https://test.example.com/home

So far in my httpd.conf file I have:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aaa/bbb/ccc$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(\.|https://|http://)example\.com(\.|/)|(\.|https://|http://)exampledev\.com(\.|/) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) / [R=403,L]
```

The above code basically looks at the query string and redirects the user to a forbidden page if example.com and exampledev.com is NOT in query_string.

This code is only doing part of the job as invalid request number 3 will be considered as containing example.com, which could be considered a phishing attack

Somehow I need to validate the domain that is returned in query_string returnurl.

The string between http:// or httpd:// a .com or .net or .org or any other top level domains.

Can someone please help or suggest how I would validate a domain that is returned as a returnurl query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aaa/bbb/ccc$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(returnurl|[&]returnurl)=(http|https)://([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]example[.]com|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]exampledev[.]com|example[.]com|exampledev[.]com)[&]{0,1}
RewriteRule ^(.*) / [R=403,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help This alows for example: returnurl=google.comsometingbad.com So far I have this code RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(returnurl|[&]returnurl)=(http|https)://(example1(\.com|\.com\.au)[/]|example2(‌​\.com|\.com\.au)[/]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]example1(\.com|\.com\.au)[/]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]ex‌​ample2(\.com|\.com\.au)[/]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]exmaple2(\.com|\.com\.au‌​)[/])[&]{0,1} This stops any string after the ".com.au" and ".com" but must have the [/]. I don't know how to say [/|<nothing>]. your help is much appreciated

Comment: This might do the job.
(\.com$|\.com\.au$|\.com/|\.com\.au/)